# Custom Date and Time String from milliseconds

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, simpledateformat, milliseconds

I have time in milliseconds for ex. `1308700800000`; I need to convert it to something like        `Jun 9'11 at 02:15 PM`.

I tried using

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM D'\''YY");
```

but i get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unterminated quote
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: pls add some code and full exception trace

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/ will make your life so much easier when handling dates and time in java

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's clear from the exception message that the problem is going to lie with your format string, in particular around the single quote part.

Looking at the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), we can see that:

> Text can be quoted using single quotes (') to avoid interpretation. "''" represents a single quote.

Thus I believe your format (for that date part, as per your existing example) can be as simple as

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d''yy")
```

There should be no need to get backslashes involved.

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'Y'`

Comment: Sorry, I was focusing on the syntax problems with the apostrophes and thus inserting them into the existing format by way of constrast.  In the interest of making this a copy-and-pasteable answer, I've updated the case of the day and year args.

Comment: As per Grooveek suggestion Caps D and Y didn't work, This did the trick SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d''yy 'at' hh:mm aaa");

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

class D {
    public static void main( String ... args )  {
        System.out.println( 
            new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd''yy")
            .format( new Date( 1308700800000L  ))
        );
    }
}
```

prints:

```
Jun 21'11
```

Answer (score 3):

Andrzej is right, but Caps D and Y won't work for you. Read the doc, but
that should work:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d''yy 'at' HH:mm:ss z")
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d''yy 'at' hh:mm aaa"); did the trick..